# imdbpy and setuptools - dependency problem

Tags: dependencies, setup.py, imdbpy

Currently I'm working on one of my first python projects so sorry in advance if some problems seems to be a bit too simple... Anyway.

My simple project uses imdbpy - Python package to access the IMDb's database (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/IMDbPY/). imdbpy depends inter alia on lxml.

Problem occurs when I try to install my project using python setup.py script.

Error message generated during installation:

** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

Using build configuration of libxslt

So I need libxml2 and libxslt but there are not accesible via pypi.

I've found similar problem on Stackoverflow: [python setuptool how can I add dependency for libxml2-dev and libxslt1-dev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493151/python-setuptool-how-can-i-add-dependency-for-libxml2-dev-and-libxslt1-dev) but answer does not solve my problem.

Is there any workaround for such dependency problem?

I can add as a side note that if libxml2-dev and libxslt1 are installed with:

sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev

then my setup script proceeds successfully.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I'm way too late, but I answer for other user that will need it in the future.

These are build dependencies, and these are not python packages, so you need the development environment for these libraries.

In general, you can use some switches of the IMDbPY setup.py to exclude these C dependencies:

```
    python setup.py install --without-lxml --without-cutils
```