# Create a Distributed Package that uses lxml

Tags: python, python-3.9

I've created a python package that uses `lxml`.
In setup.py I have defined:

```
packages=find_packages(),  # Required
python_requires='>=3.8, <4',
install_requires=[
    'typer[all]',
    'packaging',
    'lxml'
]
```

Tests, packaging and deployments work just fine.
However, after uploading the package to my company's PyPi repository, I'm trying to install the package with:

```
pip install -i <mypypirepo> <mypackage>
```

I get the a long error including:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    *********************************************************************************
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    *********************************************************************************
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python39\python.exe'
```

While trying to install manually the `lxml` I get the same exact error.

I found solutions on stackoverflow that talk about manually downloading a compatible `wheel` version of `lxml` and then installing it with `pip`.
However, the `lxml` is a part of the package that should be easily installed by the end-user.

Is there any way to solve the issue without forcing the user to manually install `lxml`?

Note: This issue only started happening after upgrading python from 3.8 to 3.9.

Comment: The issue is not related to pip. Some packages rely on system libraries, in this case it is `libxml2`. It is not the same as the PyPI package; lxml expects you to install the lbirary it manually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?" when installing lxml through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785755/getting-could-not-find-function-xmlcheckversion-in-library-libxml2-is-libxml2)

Comment: @AMC No, it doesn't, since the answer given requires the user to literally go to a website, download something and manually install it

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3493151

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing 2020-10-12 there is no lxml wheel for python 3.9 on PyPI.

If using windows like I do there are unofficial wheels here:

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)